# Cloud Functions Emulator not logging things on console.log() on Cloud Firestore triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I have successfully run Firebase emulator:

```
E:\firebase>firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore
!  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "10"
+  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
!  No Firestore rules file specified in firebase.json, using default rules.
i  firestore: Serving ALL traffic (including WebChannel) on http://localhost:808
0
!  firestore: Support for WebChannel on a separate port (8081) is DEPRECATED and
 will go away soon. Please use port above instead.
i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
+  firestore: Emulator started at http://localhost:8080
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
i  functions: Watching "E:\firebase\func
tions" for Cloud Functions...
!  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to
 E:\firebase\key.json. Non-emulated serv
ices will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
+  functions[notifyNewMessage]: firestore function initialized.
+  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

The `functions` file with `notifyNewMessage` function is below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.notifyNewMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('test/{test}')
    .onCreate((docSnapshot, context) => {    
        console.log(docSnapshot.data())
    }
```

When I create a new document manually in my Firebase console, my CLI in Windows does not log anything. How can I fix this so that it logs what the functions says in my CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local emulator doesn't respond to changes in the Firestore database that's hosted in Google's cloud and visible in the console.  What it does respond to are changes in the locally emulated Firestore database also running on your machine.  If you want your Firestore function to trigger in the local emulator, you will have to instead make a change to the emulated Firestore, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#cloud_firestore).  You might want to go through the provided [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs) to get some experience with this.

If you don't want to use the Firestore emulator and just want to trigger it directly for testing, you can use the [Firebase CLI local shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell).

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I only need to trigger it directly for testing.

Answer (score 12):

I was just being an idiot and had not re-compiled by code.

Comment: Which command you use to re-compile the ts code.

Comment: `npm run build`: `tsc`